# A system of linear equations $\begin{cases}x+2y-z=3,\\z+w=1;\end{cases}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So I've been given this system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
x + 2y - z = 3,\\
z + w = 1;
\end{cases}$$
and I had to find the solutions.

I got stuck up to

$$\begin{cases}
x+2y-(1-w)=3,\\
x+2y+w=4;
\end{cases}$$

I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: you need three linear equations to find three unknowns say $x$, $y$ & $z$. But there are four unknowns $x$, $y$ & $z$ & $w$

Comment: Do you realize you have a system of two linear equations in four variables? There is an infinite amount of possible solutions. Do you need to find just one?

Comment: The question says find all the solutions.

Comment: Maybe you need to define the range of solutions?

Answer (score 2):

We have $z=x+2y-3$ and $w=1-z=-x-2y+4$.

So if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ then $(x,y,x+2y-3,-x-2y+4)$ is a solution.

Now if $(x,y,z,w)$ is a solution it can be written as $(x,y,x+2y-3,-x-2y+4)$.

Therefore the set of solutions of this system in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is:$$S=\{(x,y,x+2y-3,-x-2y+4)\,:\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

With more linear algebra, notice that:$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},\,(x,y,x+2y-3,-x-2y+4)=(x,0,x,-x)+(0,y,2y,-2y)+(0,0,-3,4)=x(1,0,1,-1)+y(0,1,2,-2)+(0,0,-3,4)$.

Thus $$S=(0,0,-3,4)+\text{span}\{(1,0,1,-1),(0,1,2,-2)\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic equation $x^2+px+q=0$ has real roots if:
$$D=p^2-4q\ge 0.$$
The roots will have same sign if:
$$x_1\cdot x_2=q>0$$
Both roots will be positive if the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola is positive:
$$x_0=-\frac{p}{2}>0 \Rightarrow p<0$$
To summarize:
$$\begin{cases}
q\le \frac14p^2\\ 
0<q\le 1\\
-1\le p<0
\end{cases}$$

Hence:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The area of the green feasible region is:
$$\int_{-1}^0 \frac14p^2 dp=\frac1{12}p^3|_{-1}^0=\frac1{12}$$
So, the probability is:
$$\frac1{12}\cdot \frac1{4}=\frac1{48}.$$